# How compare numbers in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have two numbers that contain every one `from 1 to 6 digits`.
I would like to compare them using JavaScript and to put a percentage according their matching.

The comparison should be done from left to right.

**Example:**

```
if 6D matching then 100%  ==> Example: (value_1: 987456, value_2: 987456) 
if 5D matching then 90%   ==> Example: (value_1: 987450, value_2: 987456)
if 4D matching then 80%   ==> Example: (value_1: 987400, value_2: 987456)
if 3D matching then 60%   ==> Example: (value_1: 987000, value_2: 987456)
if 2D matching then 40%   ==> Example: (value_1: 980000, value_2: 987456)
else  0%           ==> Example: (value_1: 010101, value_2: 987456)
```

I hope that I was clear. 
Can you suggest me a solution how can I do it in a function ?
Thank you

Comment: *"The comparaison should be done from left to right."* -- You have two strings that contain only digit characters.

Comment: It's not  clear how do you deterine rhe success: In the secound exxample there was a maching of 4/5 why is it 90%? isn't supose to be 80%?

Comment: @ZivBen-Or in the second example I have the difference only in the last digit. In value_1 the last digit is 0 and in value_2 the last digit is 6. So I have 5 digits are identical

Comment: the match should be considered in order only? what for `98765` and `08765`? is it 0D match or 4D match?

Comment: @AZ_ yes in order, and I should compare from the left to the right. in you example is 0D match

Comment: the (X)D match and percentage aren't proportional. seems like switch case needs to be used here.

Comment: It appears that the OP wants the sequential non matching count deducted from 100 at a weight of 10 percentage points each, or else a result of 0% when there are no sequential matches. Sequential meaning in the digit order from left to right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply take the difference of numbers and if the difference is 0 then take empty string else the length/order of difference.

keep the percentages in an array on the index of the same order it should be.

```js
let per = [100, 90, 80, 60, 40]
calcPer = (num1, num2) => per[(Math.abs(num1 - num2) || '').toString().length] || 0;

console.log(calcPer(987456, 987456))
console.log(calcPer(987456, 987450))
console.log(calcPer(987456, 987400))
console.log(calcPer(987456, 987000))
console.log(calcPer(987456, 900000))
```

Comment: Nice! Good idea to take the difference!

Comment: what if the numbers are 987456 and 980006 ?

Comment: @FabrizioCalderan that's 2D match so 40%, what's wrong?

Comment: in this case shouldn't be 60%? 3 digits are equals

Comment: @FabrizioCalderan no, what OP wants is a sequential match from left to right

Comment: my bad, I've just seen this requirement in the comments (the most appropriate place, of course)

Answer (score 3):

Firstly transform the number to a string and iterate over them.
for example:

```js
let number1 = 12345 + ""
let number2 = 12346 + ""
let percentageMaps = ["0%", "0%", "40%", "60%", "80%", "90%", "100%"]

function getPercentage(number1, number2) {
  counter = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < number1.length; i++) {

    if (number1.charAt(i) == number2.charAt(i)) {
      counter++;
    }

  }
  return percentageMaps[counter]
}

console.log(getPercentage(number1, number2))
```

Answer (score 1):

You should do something like:

```js
let value_1 = 123456
let value_2 = 123000

let percentage = 100
while (percentage > 0 && value_1 !== value_2) {
    value_1 = Math.floor(value_1/10)
    value_2 = Math.floor(value_2/10)
    if (percentage > 80) percentage -= 10
    else if (percentage > 40) percentage -= 20
    else percentage = 0
}
console.log(percentage)
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

- Convert number to string (string1, string2)
- split one of the string greater length (string1 > string2) ? string1.split('')
- loop every element of string2
- initialize a counter to 0
- check if element of string2 exists in string1 if (string1.indexOf(string2[i]) > -1) {count += 1}
- finally for percentage (count/string1.length) * 100

`

```
var a = String(839123)
var b = String(829156)
var count = 0;
for (let i = 0 ; i < b.length; i++) {
    if (a.indexOf(b[i]) > -1) {
        count += 1;
    }
}
alert(count); //Match Count`
```