# How to compare numbers as as string in javascript

Tags: javascript

I would like to compare 2 numbers their types is string and return a pourcentage of their matching. The rule is to compare from left to right.
The numbers can contains from 1 to 6 digits:

if 6 digits are matched ==> match =100%

if 5 digits are matched ==> match = 90%

if 4 digits are matched ==> match = 80%

if 3 digits are matched ==> match = 60%

if 2 digits are matched ==> match = 40%

For the rest ==> match =0%

Example 1:

123456 and 123456 ==> match = 100%

12345 and 12345 ==> match = 90%

1234 and 1234 ==> match = 80%

123 and 123 ==> match = 60%

12 and 12 ==> match = 40%

For these case above, my function did them.
But when I have two numbers does not have the same number of digits.

Example 2:

123456 and 12 ==> match should be 40, because I compare from left to right, I have the 2 first digits are identical.

123456 and 123 ==> match should be 60. I have the 3 first digits are identical

123456 and 1234 ==> match should be 80.I have the 4 first digits are identical

123456 and 12345 ==> match should be 90. I have the 5 first digits are identical

123456 and 129876 ==> match should be 40. I have the 2 first digits are identical.

My code is:

```
function string_compare (string_1, string_2){
let per
if ((string_1.substring(0, 2) == string_2.substring(0, 2)) && (string_1.length == string_2.length) && (string_1.length == 2 || string_1.length == 2))
{
per = 40
}
else if (string_1.substring(0, 3) == string_2.substring(0, 3) && (string_1.length == string_2.length) && (string_1.length == 3 || string_1.length == 3))
{
per = 60
}
else if (string_1.substring(0, 4) == string_2.substring(0, 4) && (string_1.length == string_2.length) && (string_1.length == 4 || string_1.length == 4))
{
per = 80
}
else if (string_1.substring(0, 5) == string_2.substring(0, 5) && (string_1.length == string_2.length) && (string_1.length == 5 || string_1.length == 5))
{
per = 90
}
else if (string_1.substring(0, 6) == string_2.substring(0, 6) && (string_1.length == string_2.length) && (string_1.length == 6 || string_1.length == 6))
{
per = 100
}else {
per = 0
}
return per

}

return string_compare("126543", "120000")
```

How can I modify my function to treat / add the cases in Example 2 ?
Every thing else Example 1 and Example 2 is 0%

Thank you

Comment: In your first example, all of them should be a 100% match

Comment: Isn't this pretty much the same as [How compare numbers in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59984266)?

Comment: Can you confirm, your 1 example  right?

Comment: @LuisfelipeDejesusMunoz if I undertood well your question, I should display 100% if the 6 digits are matched. I already did it in my function. What is missing the cases in example 2

Comment: @VLAZ In the question that you put it, the function doesn't treat the cases in Example 2 in my currently question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this needs way less repetitive coding, and more … *math & logic* :-)

```
function percentdiff(numstring1, numstring2) {
  for(var i=0, l=Math.min(numstring1.length, numstring2.length); i<l; ++i) {
    if(numstring1[i] != numstring2[i]) {
      break;
    }
  }
  return [-1, -1, 40, 60, 80, 90, 100][i];
}
```

We loop over the strings character by character, up to the length of the shorter one of the two.

The loop is left, as soon as the digits in both at the current position don’t match any more for the first time.

So `i` will be the number of matching digits from the left, after the loop.

Since your percentage distribution does not follow a clear formula, I have used an array here to match the percentages, to the number of matching digits. Since that number could be less than two, I inserted two “fake” values of -1 at the beginning, so that this doesn’t throw an error.

(Only the edge case of potential input strings being longer than six digits, *and* having more than six matches, is not explicitly handled here.)

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to do doesnt make sense (or at least to me) but you can "solve your problem" with the following algorithm

```js
var num1 = "123456", num2 = "123", match = 0;

for(var i = 0; i < 6; i++){
  if(num1[i] != num2[i]){
    break;
  }  
  match += 1
}

// Shorter...
// for(var i = 0, match = 0; i < 6 && num1[i] == num2[i]; i++, match++);

var percentage;

switch(match){
    case 6: percentage = 100; break
    case 5: percentage = 90; break
    case 4: percentage = 80; break
    case 3: percentage = 60; break
    case 2: percentage = 40; break
    default: percentage = 0; break
}

console.log(percentage)
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
    let per = [0,0,40,60,80,90,100]
    calcPer = (num1, num2) => {
         num1= num1.toString();
         num2= num2.toString();
         count = 0;
         for(let i=0;i<num1.length;i++) {
           if(num1[i] == num2[i]) count += 1; 
           else break;
         }
         return per[count]
    }

console.log(calcPer(123456,123456))
console.log(calcPer(12345,12345))
console.log(calcPer(1234,1234))
console.log(calcPer(123,123))
console.log(calcPer(12,12))

console.log(calcPer(123456,12))
console.log(calcPer(123456,123))
console.log(calcPer(123456,1234))
console.log(calcPer(123456,12345))
console.log(calcPer(123456,129876))
```